# ASP.NET MVC 5 (OWIN) , isauthenticated is false after successful login on chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have created an asp.net MVC-5 application with individual user account for authentication. The login is successful with given user/pass but the Request.IsAuthenticated is always false and also there is no cookie saved for authentication on browser (Chrome). It works file on IE and Firefox. The problem is only in Chrome. I checked the chrome cookie setting an the cookie saving is enabled as well. Could someone help please?

Comment: Does the issue happen in all Chrome browsers or just a particular machine?

Comment: I have not tested on any other machine. It is just on my machine (dev)